# How to change the value of every cell in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with this column:

```
tblTransaction
( 
Transaction_ID,
Transaction_RequestTransactionCode,
Transaction_MobileErrorCode
)
```

by this query:

```
SELECT        Transaction_RequestTransactionCode, 
              SUM(case when Transaction_MobileErrorCode = '0' then 1 else 0 end) AS _Count
FROM          tblTransaction
GROUP BY Transaction_RequestTransactionCode
```

I got this result :

[image]

but the problem is here that I want to get report from this result. so I need to have name of every transaction, instead of transactionCode.

```
06 --> TransactionName1
51 --> TransactionName2
...
```

I want to change my query some thing like this:

```
if (06) then Transaction_RequestTransactionCode = TransactionName1
else if (51) then Transaction_RequestTransactionCode = TransactionName2
```

...

how can I do that without adding another table?

Thanks for any helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Case Statement`

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Transaction_RequestTransactionCode = 06 THEN 'TransactionName1'
         WHEN Transaction_RequestTransactionCode = 51 THEN 'TransactionName2'
       END      AS transaction_name,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN Transaction_MobileErrorCode = '0' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS _Count
FROM   tblTransaction
GROUP  BY CASE
            WHEN Transaction_RequestTransactionCode = 06 THEN 'TransactionName1'
            WHEN Transaction_RequestTransactionCode = 51 THEN 'TransactionName2'
          END
```

**Note :** If the `transaction_name` is stored in some other table then you can join that table and pull the respective `transaction_names`

Comment: Transaction_Name is not stored in other tables. and I got this error with your query : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.

Comment: @Elahe - as far i see there is no syntax error try once again

Answer (score 0):

User `Row_Number()`

```
SELECT        Transaction_RequestTransactionCode, 
              SUM(case when Transaction_MobileErrorCode = '0' then 1 else 0 end) AS _Count,
Row_Number () Over (Order by Transaction_RequestTransactionCode )
as 'TransactionName'+RN 
FROM          tblTransaction
GROUP BY Transaction_RequestTransactionCode
```